# how could I display more than one if/else to one ID?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

say two of the if statements below are true, how could I make them write to the same tag at different times.

```
if (a===b) {
        document.getElementById("LW").innerHTML = "statement 1"
    }
else  if (c===d) {
        document.getElementById("LW").innerHTML = "statement 2"
    }
else  if (e===f) {
        document.getElementById("LW").innerHTML = "statement 3";
    }
else {
        document.getElementById("LW").innerHTML = "";
    }
```

It would go to this

```
<p id="LW"></p>
```

for example, if two of the if statements were true, could it be possible to have one statement write to the p tag for 3 seconds, then display the next true statement? maybe a function or setTimer?

i have tried many ideas and searched all over but I can't seem to figure this one out! any help would be great! thanks in advance, I can try to explain further if necessary!

Comment: You could set the first text immediately, and could indeed make use of a SetTimeOut to update the text to the something else inside of a function. You could even only do if if a condition was met. Is that what you're asking how to do?

Comment: sort of! thanks! but what if they are all true!! is it possible to have one play after another? with a set time?

Comment: You can chain multiple setTimeouts, yes. And even have individual timers set for each change. For example, the first function could trigger after 10 seconds, the second after 5, etc.

Comment: that could work, but if the 5 second timer is not called because it is not true, won't it just sit there for 10 seconds to call the next one? this is what i would like to avoid if possible.

Comment: why have `else if` if you want all of them to execute when condition is met?

Comment: well this is just a basic mock-up of what i was working on, didn't want to paste a huge code block.

there are more conditions in my actual code, and i was looking to see if i could set timers in a way to display every true statement at  intervals.

Comment: Are there more complex rules in running one true statement after another? For example, if statement 1 and 3 are true, is there any case statement 3 will have to be run first?

Comment: no, there is no specific order i need them in, just one after another so that the p tag will display one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here. But one solution I can think of is not to use if-else, rather use just if statements and add all possible contents that needs to displayed to a array..

Later with an interval, you can keep toggling the contents of the array.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

 <p>Click the button.</p>

 <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('LW').value = 'statement 1';
  var contents = [];
  var i = 0;
  var count = 0;
  var a=1, b=1,c=2,d=2,e=3,f=3, g=4, h=5;
  if (a === b) {
    contents.push("statement 1");
    count++;
  }
  if (c === d) {
    contents.push("statement 2");
    count++;
  }
  if (e === f) {
    contents.push("statement 3");
    count++;
  }

  if (g === h) {
    contents.push("statement 3");
    count++;
  }

    setInterval(function(){ 
    i++;
    document.getElementById('LW').value = contents[i%count] 
  }, 1000);
}

</script>

            <label for="LW"></label><input type="text" id="LW"><label id="LWlabel"></label>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you! if you don't mind how could i write this?

Comment: thank you very much @praveen! i will try to use this!